# Create a function that will call a specific database

Tags: python, sql-server

I am exploring how SQL Server works. I have list of databases in my SQL and I want to know how to create a function that will call a specific database?

Example: mssql.getReadTable('sampleTable')

PS. I already have my connectiion string of my SQL Server so this is just my problem.

Thank you, appreciate it a lot.

Comment: a select looks like: select * from databaseName.schemaName.tableName in mssql. Usually schemaName is dbo. So, in the most simple form, your function should just build a select like that and execute it. There are tons of tutorials on how to actually execute and read data in python from sql server